# Why Do I have an '=' sign output and 2 smiley faces instead of the correct output? C++

Tags: c++, class

this is an update to show chages, details below.
  here is a link to snap shot of output
    https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34875891/wrongoutput.PNG

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstring>

    using namespace std;

    //create HotelRoom class

    class HotelRoom
    {
    private:
        char* ptr_guest;
        char room_number[3];
        int room_capacity;
        int occupancy_status;
        double daily_rate;

    public:
        HotelRoom(char roomNumber[], int roomCapacity, double roomRate, char* ptr_name, int occupancyStatus);
        ~HotelRoom();
        void Display_Number();
        void Display_Guest();
        int Get_Capacity();
        int Get_Status();
        double Get_Rate();

        int Change_Status(int);
        double Change_Rate(double);
    };
    HotelRoom::HotelRoom(char roomNumber[], int roomCapacity, double roomRate, char* ptr_name, int occupancyStatus)
    {
        strcpy(room_number, roomNumber);
        room_capacity = roomCapacity;
        daily_rate = roomRate;
        ptr_guest = new char[strlen(ptr_name) + 1];
        strcpy(ptr_guest, ptr_name);
        occupancy_status = occupancyStatus;
    }
    HotelRoom::~HotelRoom()
    {

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Destructor Executed";
        cout << endl;
        delete [] ptr_guest;
    }
    void HotelRoom::Display_Guest()
    {
        char* temp = ptr_guest;
        while(*temp != '\0')
            cout << *temp++;
    }
    void HotelRoom::Display_Number()
    {
        cout << room_number;
    }
    int HotelRoom::Get_Capacity()
    {
        return room_capacity;
    }
    int HotelRoom::Get_Status()
    {
        return occupancy_status;
    }
    double HotelRoom::Get_Rate()
    {
        return daily_rate;
    }
    int HotelRoom::Change_Status(int roomStatus)
    {
        if(roomStatus <= room_capacity )
        {
            occupancy_status = roomStatus;
            return occupancy_status;
        }
        else
            occupancy_status = -1;


    }
    double HotelRoom::Change_Rate(double newRate)
    {
        daily_rate = newRate;
        return daily_rate;
    }

    int main()
    {
        cout << setprecision(2)
             << setiosflags(ios::fixed)
             << setiosflags(ios::showpoint);

        //Declare variables to hold data

             char roomNumber[3] = {'1','3','\0'};

             char guestName[20];

             double roomRate = 89.00;

             int roomCapacity = 4;
             int occupancyStatus = 0;
             int status;
             int checkOut;
             int newCustomer;

        //Ask for user input
             cout << "What is the guest's name: ";
             cin.getline(guestName, 20);

             cout << endl;
             cout << "How many guests will be staying in the room: ";
             cin >> status;

             HotelRoom HotelRoom1(roomNumber, roomCapacity, roomRate, guestName, status);

        //Display Rooom information

             cout << endl;
             cout << endl;
             if(HotelRoom1.Change_Status(status))
             {
                 cout << endl;
                cout << "Guest's Name: ";
                HotelRoom1.Display_Guest();
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "The capacity of this room is " << HotelRoom1.Get_Capacity() << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "There are " << HotelRoom1.Get_Status() << " guests staying in the room";
             }

             cout << endl;
             cout << endl;
             cout << "Your room number is " << HotelRoom1.Display_Number();
             cout << endl;
             cout << endl;
             cout << "The rate for this room is " << HotelRoom1.Get_Rate();
             cout << endl;
             cout << endl;

        //chech this guest out?

             cout << "Check this guest out? ('1 = yes' '0' = no) ";
             cin >> checkOut;

             switch(checkOut)
             {
                 case 1:
                     HotelRoom1.Change_Status(0);
                     for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
                     {
                        cout << endl;
                     }
                     cout << "You have checked out of room number " << HotelRoom1.Display_Number();
                     cout << endl;
                     cout << endl;
                     cout << "The capacity of this room is " << HotelRoom1.Get_Capacity();
                     cout << endl;
                     cout << endl;
                     cout << "There are currently " << HotelRoom1.Get_Status() << " occupants";
                     cout << endl;
                     cout << endl;
                     cout << "The rate of this room was " << HotelRoom1.Get_Rate();
                     break;
             }

        //check in new guest?

             cout << endl;
             cout << endl;
             cout << "Check in new guest? ('1 = yes' '0' = no) ";
             cin >> newCustomer;
             for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
                {
                    cout << endl;
                }
             switch (newCustomer)
             {
             case 1:
                HotelRoom HotelRoom2(roomNumber, roomCapacity, roomRate, guestName, status);
                HotelRoom1.Change_Rate(175.00); //Change rate of room

                cout << endl;
                cout << "What is the guest's name: ";
                cin.getline(guestName, 20);
                cout << endl;
                cout << "How many guests will be staying in the room: ";
                cin >> status;
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;

        //Display new guest information

                if(HotelRoom1.Change_Status(status))
                {
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "The capacity of this room is " << HotelRoom1.Get_Capacity() << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "There are " << HotelRoom1.Get_Status() << " guests staying in the room";
                }

                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Your room number is " << HotelRoom1.Display_Number();
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;
                cout << "The rate for this room is " << HotelRoom1.Get_Rate();
                cout << endl;
                cout << endl;

                 break;
             }
             cout << endl;


        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
```

this is an update to show chages, details below.
  here is a link to snap shot of output
    https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34875891/wrongoutput.PNG

Comment: I'd guess that, with all that C-style pointer-juggling, you either forget to terminate a string or delete it before you print it. I'd use `std::string` instead. But that's far too much code for me to read through on a Sunday.

Comment: Do you have some good reason for using `char roomNumber[]` over a `std::string`?

Comment: I am using char roomNumber[] instead of string because my book, C++ for business programmers, says to use char and char pointers; my assignment also specifies to use char.

Comment: in addition, in my class's Display_Guest & Display_Number if I say return ptr_guest; or return room_number; it errors saying that you cannot "return" a pointer. Which is why I use cout to print out to screen when it is called.

Comment: If you dropped the `return` statement from your function, you also need to change the return type, to `void`.

Comment: Also, you absolutely *can* return a pointer from a function.  The problem with your previous code was something else.

Comment: Your code is definitely not compiling.  The output you are getting must be from a previous incarnation of your code.

Answer (score 4):

```
char HotelRoom::Display_Guest()
{
    cout << ptr_guest;
}

string HotelRoom::Display_Number()
{
    cout << room_number;
}

int HotelRoom::Change_Status(int roomStatus)
{
    if(roomStatus <= room_capacity )
    {
        occupancy_status = roomStatus;
        return occupancy_status;
    }
    else
        occupancy_status = -1;
}
```

These functions claim to be returning values.  The first two are not, the last is not under certain conditons.  Calling the first two is undefined behavior.  Calling `Change_Status` with `roomStatus > room_capacity` is also undefined behavior.

There may be other problems with the code, but the elephant in the room is the undefined behavior.  Any other debugging while you have undefined behavior is theoretically a waste of time.